# How to query unspecific field name using room?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I want to make a `WHERE` query in android without naming the specific field name.
namely, I want to make a `WHERE` query without defining the field name (it will determine at runtime).

I tried to do something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Workspace WHERE :name = :value")
int countFieldsFor(String name, String value)
```

But it's not working...

How can I implement this? Even by querying directly to the database (without room)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @RawQuery and simply pass generated SQL to dao interface method:

```
@Dao interface RawDao { 
    @RawQuery 
    User getUserViaQuery(SupportSQLiteQuery query); 
  } 

   SimpleSQLiteQuery query = new SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM User WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1", new Object[]{userId});
     User user2 = rawDao.getUserViaQuery(query);
```

Comment: So I can use the `SimpleSQLiteQuery` to create regular SQL query?

Comment: Thanks it works!